# Can Widgets have one "joint" state?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to implement a custom radio button, but I can select all of them, and of course, the "radio" means, I can choose only one.

My code:

```
class RadioSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  const RadioSelect(this.text, this.index, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final String text;
  final int index;
  @override
  _RadioSelectState createState() => _RadioSelectState();
}

class _RadioSelectState extends State<RadioSelect> {
  int sizeIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          sizeIndex = widget.index;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 8, 12, 8),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, top: 8),
        width: 70,
        height: 55,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(
              width: 3,
              color: sizeIndex == widget.index
                  ? Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 195, 74)
                  : Colors.white,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10) //         <--- border radius here
            )),
        child: Text(
          widget.text,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know this is because every `RadioSelect()` is a different instance, but how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it based on the [`Radio` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html):

1. Change your widget to a `StatelessWidget`.

```dart
class RadioSelect extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

2. Create a `isSelected` property and set your widget layout based on this property.

```dart
class RadioSelect extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSelected;

  const RadioSelect({this.isSelected});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // Some logic based on isSelected
      color: isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```

3. Create a `onChanged` property and, every time the user clicks on it, call this property.

```dart
class RadioSelect extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() onChanged;
  final bool isSelected;

  const RadioSelect({this.isSelected, this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      // Use onChanged as callback
      onTap: () => onChanged(),
      child: Container(
        color: isSelected ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when you have to use multiple instances of it, you can use a index to keep track of what radio is currently selected:

```dart
class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {
  // Keeping track of the number of ratios you are using
  final int _numRadios = 10;
  int _currentIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < _numRatios; i++)
          RadioSelect(
            // The radio is select if the current index of this widget
            // is equal to the current index of this child in the Column
            isSelected: _currentIndex == i,
            // When the user taps one ratio, updte the current index
            // of this widget and set a new state
            onChanged: () => setState(() => _currentIndex = i),
          )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** The code above considers the layout of all ratios are equal. If each ratio must have its own text, for example, you can replace `_numRatios` with a list of strings or a more descriptive data object:

```dart
class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {
  final List<String> texts = ["radio1", "radio2", "radio3", "radio4"];
  int _currentIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++)
          RadioSelect(
            // Supposing you have a text property in your RadioSelect
            // Access the text of the current child in the list of strings
            text: texts[i],
            isSelected: _currentIndex == i,
            onChanged: () => setState(() => _currentIndex = i),
          )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```